# SQL query to return from predefined data when not found in database data

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I need some help wrapping my head around doing the following.

I have a predefined list if ID numbers, we'll call them `Alias`, which I get from a CSV file. What I'm trying to do is compare that list to my database and find which ones exist in the CSV but NOT in the SQL database.

First thing is I'm unsure as to how to define a list of say `1,2,3,4,5` as a table with the column name as `Alias` so that I can join / select from that.

Secondly, how would you go about writing this query? I was thinking of having to structure it something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (1,2,3,4,5) WHERE Alias NOT IN (
SELECT Alias FROM table1 WHERE Alias IN (1,2,3,4,5));
```

I'm aware that this query wouldn't work, think of it more like pseudo-code, but even if something like that were to work, writing out that list twice could prove to be troublesome (I can have upwards of 50K alias' in the list) and most likely horribly inefficient.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: compare that list to my database and find which ones exist in the CSV but NOT in the SQL database.... can u xplain more here?

Comment: Hey mate, I think it just clicked for me. See the answer I just posted. I'll leave the thread here anyway though in case someone finds it one day

Answer (score 1):

After a coffee and a quick break I think I have the best solution.

Considering this is going to be a stored procedure anyway, the stored procedure will take the following action.

1. Create `TempTable` IF NOT EXISTS, TRUNCATE if it does
2. INSERT (CSVList) INTO `TempTable`
3. `SELECT Alias FROM TempTable WHERE Alias NOT IN (SELECT Alias FROM MainTable)`

This way I can specify that list as a table and select from it only once :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your CSV values (comma separated) in `T` table, and `T1` is your MainTable. Then following is the code that may help you. And this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8046e/1) that I tried.

**Stage 1:** Make your horizontal comma separated data into column data.

```
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS data  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([id], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  T) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Here `T` is your table and `id` is the column name that has comma separated data.

**Stage 2:** Now merge this query with your main table to get the result.

```
select * from 

  (SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS data  
 FROM  (SELECT   
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([id], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  T) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)) as CSV

where data not in (select * from T1)
```

Comment: oh boy that's intense! I'll have a play with it and work on actually understanding it. Thanks!

Comment: @SeanMissingham Check the SQLFiddle that I tried.. and feel free to post if you have any other problem, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For performance and efficiency, please use NOT EXISTS in comparing the 2 table outputs.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tbl2 t2 WHERE t2.Col1 = t1.Col1)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that was even a thing, I suppose I just always assumed NOT IN was the better / only means. Care to elaborate on why?

Comment: Do some RnD on "NOT IN" or how sub-query or inner query works in SQL; considering the fact that the left/primary table looks up each record in the right/inner tables' query output. The "EXISTS" clause is an optimized way of obtaining the required results, as returns TRUE for the condition the moment it matches.